# How do I fetch data from SQL after sorting and making sure none are repeated

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

So I have a database and the table has heads like "LAT, LNG, NAME, EMAIL, DATE, TIME"

This is to show markers on a map by connecting the php map page with the DB to fetch the data.

Now my question is:

For eg: 
I have datasets with email ID: abc@gmail.com repeated for 10 times. Each with different LAT and LONG.
I have datasets with email ID: xyz@gmail.com repeated for 10 times. Each with different LAT and LONG.
I have datasets with email ID: efg@gmail.com repeated for 10 times. Each with different LAT and LONG.

How do I only fetch the latest datasets only? Instead of 30 markers, I want only 3 latest markers.

I can sort it with the date and time of the insert but how do I set it to only receive one of each.

MY SQL query: `$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT email, latitude, longitude, name from test ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC";`

I tried DISTINCT and also tried DESC LIMIT 1 but both didn't get the desired results. No error messages either. What am I missing?

Please help me figure this out.

Regards
Abhisar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from test t
where concat(t.date, ' ', t.time) = (
    select max(concat(t1.date, ' ', t1.time))
    from test t1
    where t1.email = t.email
)
```

Note that you should not be storing the date and time components in two different columns. This makes things more complicated when you need to actually generate a legitimate `datetime` value - and efficiency will suffer from that.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. That really helped. I'm new to this.. could it be possible for you to explain the above statement. Also.. will change date and time to datetime.